# SWFObject is undefined

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I'm getting the following error in my Flash Builder project. This is my file structure

- Flex Project
- src
- lib
- bin
- html-template

  ```
  Webpage error details

  User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
  Timestamp: Wed, 19 Jan 2011 13:29:11 UTC


  Message: Invalid character
  Line: 1
  Char: 1
  Code: 0
  URI: file:///D:/branches/v0.0/flash/bin/swfobject.js


  Message: 'swfobject' is undefined
  Line: 50
  Char: 13
  Code: 0
  URI: file:///D:/branches/v0.0/flash/bin/something.html
  ```

Now, if I move swfObject.js into the bin folder. On debug it starts working fine. But when I do a debug again. Builder automatically deletes the Swfobject.js and the error is back again.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't you move swfobject.js to the html-template directory? I think on each compile the bin folder is deleted and recreated with the content of the html template, plus the new swf file.

Comment: @Fahim:Whats is giving the error? Also, you provided a "file structure" with only directories on it...

Answer (score 0):

@goliatone is right, put all HTML / JS files you want to use in the html-template folder. When you run / debug your application, all the files will be placed into the bin-debug (or the folder you have selected), together with the .SWF-file.

Sometimes, 'Project' -> 'clean' can avoid some problems like these...

Comment: That is the whole issue I have everything in the html-template folder and that is when I get the error. When I move it to bin the error stops for one build. Then comes again.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your 'Build path' property window, and maybe your file tree?